LangGraph deployment with docker-compose
I'm following the deployment guidelines from https://academy.langchain.com to run a LangGraph agent. I got stuck with deployment of langgraph-api, redis and postgres with docker-compose.
The project structure looks like this:
project
├── .env
├── langgraph.json
├── docker-compose.yml
└── src
    └── agent
        └── agent.py

When I run langgraph build -t aa-image, it all passes fine. I'm also able to run langgraph dev, all works good.
I copied an example of docker-compose.yml from LangChain Academy GitHub (I replaced the environment variables):

volumes:
    langgraph-data:
        driver: local
services:
    langgraph-redis:
        image: redis:6
        healthcheck:
            test: redis-cli ping
            interval: 5s
            timeout: 1s
            retries: 5
    langgraph-postgres:
        image: postgres:16
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        volumes:
            - langgraph-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        healthcheck:
            test: pg_isready -U postgres
            start_period: 10s
            timeout: 1s
            retries: 5
            interval: 5s
    langgraph-api:
        image: "aa-image"
        ports:
            - "8123:8000"
        depends_on:
            langgraph-redis:
                condition: service_healthy
            langgraph-postgres:
                condition: service_healthy
        environment:
            REDIS_URI: redis://langgraph-redis:6379
            OPENAI_API_KEY: "I replaced this..."
            LANGSMITH_API_KEY: "... and this"
            POSTGRES_URI: postgres://postgres:postgres@langgraph-postgres:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable

When I run docker-compose up, I get the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/deps/__outer_src/src/agent\\agent.py'
Could not find python file for graph: GraphSpec(id='aa_agent', path='/deps/__outer_src/src/agent\\agent.py', module=None, variable='graph', config=None)

What should I do to make it see the ./src/agent/agent.py file? I tried moving Python source from the src to root folder, but it didn't help. There's very little info about what langgraph CLI tool does and how.
Here's also the content of langgraph.json:
{
    "dockerfile_lines": [],
    "graphs": {
        "aa_agent": "./src/agent/agent.py:graph"
    },
    "env": ".env",
    "python_version": "3.12",
    "dependencies": ["./src"]
}

